# Export to with Excel 2016 extension xlsx in Asp .Net Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

Whenever I try to download excel file it saves it as Excel version of 1997-2003 and I used all content types and could not find the solution as it still saves it as 'xls' not 'xlsx'.

I have an Export method which has the following code.

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename = " + fileName);
```

Comment: What does `fileName` contain?

Comment: I'm sure you are adding `xls` extension in your `fileName`.

Comment: The content type "application/ms-excel" is used for .xls file while "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" is used for .xlsx file(V2007 or Above).
I suggest you to refer about "closedxml". It will resolve your problem.

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) for example.